# What is a flavor(s) in graphic design?

Tags: print-design, terminology

I am creating a logo for an upcoming event, and I was asked to submit “flavors” for vector graphics and B/W. This is probably a given that all designers should know (I’m an IA architect), but what are flavors?

From Google search, I get a lot of results with companies that include *flavor* in their company name or edible products – so that’s no help at all. I’m assuming it’s a type of format, but I would like to be corrected if I am wrong.

Comment: No, this is not an industry term at all. Ask them what they meant.

Answer (score 1):

Hum... This is a gess, but I think they are refering to "style" probably one with some gradient, a version on just one ink, one specific with black ink, one version for dark background.

If it is on the revisions stage could be to decide which look to choose.

Answer (score 0):

As Rafael suggested, "flavor" in that context means they want to see different variations of the logo.

**In other words, they just want to see a set of drafts, a proof with a few suggestions for the logos! Nothing special, just another way to ask you to prepare more than one logo to choose from.**

You should simply create a few different drafts of logos to choose from and ask for their feedback. Then tweak the ones they prefer until they select one. They don't mean to prepare the same logo with different variations; they probably mean different suggestions of different logo design.

At the first drafts, you don't need to spend too much time showing the logo with different variations of the same logo applied in different situations; you can simply present 2-5 drafts, and a black version for each of them as well. Later you can show them the logo in other contexts once it's closer to be final.... to help them select the best one.

Of course if you have a good budget for this, you can prepare many logos and show different variations of each but from experience I can tell you it's better to not show too many!

Answer (score -2):

Okay, this is not an answer - flavor generally means a style or taste. I tried to imagine what a flavor would look like.

I found:

[Wiley Flavour and Fragrance Journal](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ffj.v30.4/issuetoc)

which is interesting.

Then:

[Wix Templates](http://www.wix.com/website/templates/html/all/1)

which if you call each style a flavor, you're getting there. I would call the first one (IP Law Firm - Kant & Rider) mint, but I got a bit stuck after that.

But then I found this:

[Silk](https://silk.com/our-story/our-promise)

which I think is quite cool.

Comment: That first link appears to be about medical allergies. The last link is a non-dairy milk product. I don't know how this answers the question.

Comment: each color is given by a fruit or vegetable, with its own **flavor**!